# Spring MVC isn't inserting value in foreign key

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, integer, int, one-to-many

i really need some help and cant find the answer anywhere, and probably really basic

i am trying to create a crud with spring MVC , and it is working with a single table, but when trying to add a second one with in a one to many relationship spring doesn't apply the value to the foreign key field. every time i end up with a "HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect." and nothing show up at the log. Any hints in the right directions will be appreciated.

==========================================================================
CODE:
i am using jpacontroler generated by netbeans which is working fine

======================JSP

> ```
>  <form:form action="cadbloco.htm" modelAttribute="bloco" method="GET" >
>
>             Nome
>             <input type="text"  name="nomebloco" placeholder="nome" /> <br/>
>             numero
>             <input type="text"  name="numerobloco"  /><br/>
>             condominio
>             <input type="text"   name="condominioIdcondominio"  /><br/>
>            <br/>
>
>             <input type="submit" value="cadbloco" />
>
>         </form:form>
> ```

======================Controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value="cadbloco", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String cadbloco(  @ModelAttribute(value="Bloco")  Bloco bloco , Model model) {

      //  model.addAttribute("bloco", new Bloco());
        BlocoJpaController jpa = new BlocoJpaController();

        jpa.create(bloco);

         return "redirect:bloco.htm";

    }
```

===============entity1

> ```
> @JoinColumn(name = "condominio_idcondominio", referencedColumnName = "idcondominio")
> @ManyToOne(optional = false)
> private Condominio condominioIdcondominio;
> ```

===============entity2

```
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "condominioIdcondominio")
    private List<Bloco> blocoList;
```

Comment: can you show the sql generated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for your attention , but i finally found the awnser
I tried to translate it to English to make more sense:

> @RequestMapping(value = "register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
>       public String cadbloco(@ModelAttribute(value = "Owner") Owner owner @RequestParam("Car") int idcar) {
>
> ```
>     Owner owner = new Owner();
>     Owner.setIdOwner(Ownerid);
>
>     CarJpaController jpa = new CarJpaController();
>     car.setCondominioIduser(owner);
>     jpa.create(owner);
>
>     return ("redirect:user.htm");
> ```

My mistake was not to specify the second object, since it is java and not sql.
it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the *referencedColumnName*, since you do not need to reference to another column because it is already done by *mappedBy*.

I hope this helps.